# CS0229 error when making a camera controller in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting a CS0229 error when making a camera controller in unity.

Here is the error: CS0229 Ambiguity between 'CameraController.doMovement' and 'CameraController.doMovement'

I am new to unity and to C# so I have no clue what is causing this error or how to fix it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float panSpeed = 30f;
    public float panBorderThichness = 10f;
    public float scrollSpeed = 5f;
    public float minY = 10f;
    public float maxY = 80f;

    private bool doMovement = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            doMovement = !doMovement;
        }
        if (!doMovement)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.height - panBorderThichness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s") || Input.mousePosition.y <= panBorderThichness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d") || Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - panBorderThichness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.mousePosition.x <= panBorderThichness)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * panSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.y -= scroll * scrollSpeed * 1000 * Time.deltaTime;
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, minY, maxY);
        transform.position = pos;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrip CameraController.cs got duplicated somehow.